# SELECT row for certain date in unix time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, pdo

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date = :date";
$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(':date' => mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y)));
```

I have `date` field in unix format (created with `time()` function). How to select rows that were created in custom day, month and year ($d, $m, $y)?

Comment: What is the type of the `date` column?

Comment: `bigint(20)`. Is it good type?

Comment: I'd recommend you to set it as `TIMESTAMP`. It will help you later when it will automatically make conversions for you when you compare it with date strings for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select a day you should probably change your query into

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date >= :date AND date <= :date + 86400
```

I haven't tested this though so it might be wrong, but the logic is that.

Comment: Care: I wrote 86400 but instead it should be 86399, otherwise you would have the first second of the next day included in your range.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) (uses index if you have it on `date` field):

```
$sql = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM mytable 
    WHERE date BETWEEN :dateF AND :dateT
";
$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(
    ':dateF' => mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y),
    ':dateT' => mktime(23, 59, 59, $m, $d, $y),
));
```